# Pass ID or Object which has irrelavant details as RequestBody in Rest Call?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, oop, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

**Approach 1:**

```
@PostMapping("/api/{id}")
String getSomeObj(int id){
    //make another rest call with id and get CustomObj
    // then do some logic and return something
    //Here response time will be more as it has again another rest calls

}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
@PostMapping("/api/{id}")
String getSomeObj(@PathParam("id") int id, @RequestBody CustomObj obj){
    //directly do logic with the provided obj and return something
    //Here Response time would be less as we are directly getting the actual Object from Request Body
    //BUT is this a good practise to pass an object in which we need only few details?
}
```

**Q1)** All I am asking is to whether to pass just id or Object? If id is passed, another Rest call has to be made unnecessarily. If Object is passed, we can avoid making another rest call, BUT the problem is: this custom object may contain some irrelavant details too.. So, is this correct?

**Q2)** If passed with id, response time will be more when comparing with just passing object.. So, I am not understanding which approach should follow..

Answer (score 2):

A1) This is all up to you and there is no "one correct" way. I would say if it's a small object pass the object and respond fast. If its a big object pass the id. How do you define big and small objects? if object has hashmaps or lists in it that's a big object. Also you can ignore serialization of internals; check https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

A2) Pass the id and enjoy your REST service. After all REST is very fast. Don't worry about the speed of calls. If your back end function is fast and if you put a "loading" gif to front end; users will wait for the response.